# EasyAR : turning on flash (torch mode) on my Android device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, easyar

How to turn on Flash light on my Android device using EasyAR with Unity Engine with a C# code

(Torch Mode )

With a button to turn ON and a Button to turn off

I need a code in C# and
Where i should attach this code

Using EasyAR to create Augmented Reality App